# Ionic/Cordova: How to debug JavaScript codes that require "cordova.js" library in a web-browser

Tags: javascript, cordova, google-chrome, debugging, ionic-framework

I am developing an app for Androind using Ionic framework.
The app uses Cordova Medila plugin and to use that I need to include:

```
<script src="cordova.js"></script>
```

in my html code. This is required to be able to run the code on Android, however there is not a `cordova.js` in the www directory and Ionic finds it in one of its subfolders when it wants to build for Android.

I need to debug the code and want to run the JavaScript line by line in Chrome, but becuase chrome cannot find `cordova.js`, it gives error (like "gap_init:2").

I tried to find a copy of `cordova.js` in a sub-folder of the app that belongs to Android platform and copy it to `www\js` folder but when tried to run my html code I got strange errors during loading of the html file.

My question is:
Is it possible to debug these applications in Chrome? If it is how? If it is not, are there IDEs or tools that can be used for debug?

Comment: This error always happens when you are debugging a cordova-ionic app in chrome, but doesn't break the code at all, you still can debug the rest of your application. Don't bother yourself in fixing it

Answer (score 2):

Try the link chorme inspect, we used to debug the android apps
https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/debug/remote-debugging/remote-debugging?hl=en

Comment: I would say this is the best answer. Once you have build your app in your phone and the app is running and the phone is connected to your pc just open this url on your chrome browser -> chrome://inspect/#devices (there you can see your connected device and inspect it like you would normally in chrome devtools).

Comment: @Naveen Bannikoppa: thank you very much for the help. That works partially. Now I am getting this error when I open the Developer Tools and try to inspect my code: "Uncaught ReferenceError: Media is not defined". The error belongs to this line of code: `myMedia = new Media(src, onSuccess, onError); `. To use Media I have installed Cordova media plugin. Is there anything I can do to resolve this?

Comment: Add <script src="cordova.js"></script>  now

Answer (score 0):

cordova.js you cant see in www directory it will automatic added cordova.js when you deploy your code on android device using this command  "ionic run android"

Comment: That's is true but if I want to run on Chrome to debug it gives error and says it cannot find cordova.js.

Comment: can you tell what type of app are you developing ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can debug cordova apps in chrome.
here are the steps

- goto cordova project path
- add a browser platform using command `cordova platform add browser`
- run browser platform using command `cordova run browser`

after doing so, your app will run in new window of chrome with all plugins proxy added as required
like this 
[image: console]
[image: all the js will be added automatically.]

all the JS's will be added automatically and you will be able to see the code of cordova.js and debug it from sources tab.

Comment: you can also try visual studio 2015, it provides tools to debug app on device.